# TF2 Voting Options

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

I run a TF2 server, and I want to customise the in-game vote menu, without using sourcemod. The reason is, I want to add extra MVM maps (not official ones) and I want the players to be able to select which map they want to play by the vote features.

Comment: do you want a mod or do you want to DIY

Comment: I'd be quite happy to DIY - I expressly do not want to use sourcemod or any other third party plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the way to do this:

First of all, in your server.cfg, set the `tf_mvm_missioncyclefile` parameter. The default file this points to gets overwritten on server updates.

Then, copy the file `tf_mvm_missioncycle.res` to your chosen file set in the parameter above.

Finally, edit this file to taste (I won't provide example here, its fairly straightforward).